# How to force datasource to be updated from TemplateControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, controltemplate

I broke my head by solving a simple problem. I have a custom control with filled Template property. The template is a simple Grid with a TextBox inside. This text box is bound to a singleton's proprty with setter and getter. How can I programmatically force the TextBox to read value from the singleton and put it back?

```
<Window x:Class="Spike.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="305" Width="521" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Spike" xmlns:Data="clr-namespace:Spike.Data">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="editingTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static Data:MyClass.Instance}, Path=Value2}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <UserControl Template="{StaticResource editingTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,60,0,0" x:Name="myUserControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="75" Width="284" />
        <Button Content="Update source" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,23,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111" Click="button1_UpdateSource" Focusable="False" />
        <Button Content="Update control" Focusable="False" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,23,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111" Click="button2_UpdateControl" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
namespace Spike.Data
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private static readonly MyClass MyClassInstance = new MyClass();

        public MyClass()
        {
            Value1 = "value1";
            Value2 = "value2";
        }

        public static MyClass Instance
        {
            get { return MyClassInstance; }
        }

        public string Value1 { get; set; }

        public string Value2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In other words what should be implemented in **button2_UpdateControl** and **button1_UpdateSource** methods?

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

A Binding shouldn't be re-invoked manually. Instead, you should try and make your current Binding mechanism work properly.
Your TextBox should bind to [DependancyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) or the DataContext of the TextBox should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).
Define your `Value2` property like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty Value2Property = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value2", typeof(string), typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

public string Value2
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(Value2Property); }
    set { SetValue(Value2Property, value); }
}
```

Also, MyClass should implement UIElement.

Comment: MyClass can implement INotifyPropertyChanged - this is not a problem. But I want to understand how the UserControl without any knowelage about its template can force the TextBox update value in a bound object.

Comment: UserControl is not forcing TextBox to update. The TextBox binds to events and responds to those events, that's what updating the TextBox. The UserControl doesn't know or care what TextBox is bound to. It is just serving as a container (in your scenario) to other controls which can have separate binding contexts.

Comment: Ok, Let's say that the user control is a cell in a grid which can have several templates: 1. one in a normal state. 2. another template while data editing. When the user clicks on a cell, the grid changes templates. While setting a new template, it gets a value from a data object. When the editing control losts a focus - it tries to call propertie's setter with some validation process. Is it possible to force this control to commit modified value programmatically without loosing the focus?

Comment: Everything is possible, you just need to be aware how DataContext, triggers and binding works. If you setup everything properly, you can achieve what you want. However, without exact code, I cannot tell you more than what you specifically ask.

Comment: The code I've provided is very close to my real example. Text box gets a value at the beginning, but I don't understand how to implement button1_UpdateSource(). If you put button1.Focusable to true, when the user clicks on the button, it gets a focus and therefore TextBox updates a value in the bound object. My question: How is it possible to do programmatically without focus changing?

Comment: I tried to use myUserControl1.BindingGroup.BindingExpressions, but it doesn't contains expressions of the templated control. Any ideas... May be routed commands, but which?